# Unable to change the icon color when mouse is over the image in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, upi

I want to change the icon color while cursor is over it. Below is the code I have written:

```
 <Image Name="PreviousBtn" Stretch="Fill"  Height="20" MouseUp="LoadPrevious_Click" ToolTip="Load Previous Study" Cursor="Hand">
     <Image.Style>
       <Style TargetType="Image">
          <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                 <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/Previous.png"/>
                 <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
             </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>`enter code here`
    </Image.Style>
 </Image>
```

I am not getting the  'Previous.png' on UI. and so , 'IsMouseOver' property is not at all working.

Anyone has having any idea.

Comment: IsMouseOver will never be true on an empty Image. What are you trying to achieve? Is this supposed to act like a Button that only shows its Content when the mouse is over it?

Comment: I want to get the background  color of image be changed when mouse is over it.

<Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/Previous.png"/>

This path conains that image

Comment: "background color of image" - that is not what you are showing in your XAML. There is no image before the Setter in the Trigger has been executed.

Comment: If you have any idea how to write, please do mention ...

Comment: How is the image supposed to look like when the mouse is not over it?

Comment: You haven't answered my question: "Is this supposed to act like a Button that only shows its Content when the mouse is over it?"

Comment: Yes... it suppose to act like button. We have triggered an event with that image, when clicked

Comment: Come on, that is only half of what I asked. What about the "*only shows its Content when the mouse is over it*" part? Should it be empty when the mouse is not over it?

Comment: @mm8, It looks like normal image, but it should act like button.
I got some idea from MSDN, but this didn't work for me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover?view=netframework-4.7.2

In my section I'm not getting below code option in mine:

<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />

Comment: @Clemens, it should not be empty. It is just an image and act look like a image only. Just need to be color change so that it looks like responsive icons.

Comment: And you have two different PNGs for both states? It is really hard to help you when you don't tell us all relevant details.

Comment: @Rajesh: Color change? Do you mean that you want to change from one default image to another one when you move the mouse over the image?

Comment: @Clemens, I am giving clear requirement now, as below:

I have requirement that if I am clicking on image then some action would be performed. and its performing as well. But I want some responsive deviation should come on that icon if mouse is over it. So I want some color deviation in the icon if mouse goes over it. I have only one image only. No separate image.
This is all I want to do .

Comment: @mm8, I have mentioned the requirement

Comment: Note that there is nothing like "the color" of a bitmap (which is what a PNG is decoded to). Even then, it would be difficult to change it from a Setter. Consider using a Path element with an icon geometry, where you can change the Fill or Stroke property.

Answer (score -1):

Put some Container like Grid or Button around the Image to have the "IsMouseOver" Property

Comment: Code is inside stack panel:

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">


</StackPanel>